# What is the best MySQL table structure.. or the best way to query my existing structure?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a website where users have core data about their profile (user_name, email, preferences, etc) as well as arbitrary data that could change on the fly. Not all users would necessarily have a need for all data fields. Thus on my tblUsers MySQL table, I don't want to add a bunch of columns that might only be practical to a small percentage of users.

The way I imagined would be to create a second table, with the following columns:
UID INT, dataType TINYINT, dataValue INT

Basically UID would point to the User's ID in the users table (tlbUsers) and the dataType would point to an ID in a list (another table) of dataTypes, such as "Age", "Favorite Color", "Points", etc.

The problem is, when I say:
"SELECT * FROM tblUsers, tblData WHERE UID=ID"
I get several rows stacked (which works well enough...)
But I can't figure out how to write a query which takes the tblData information into consideration.

For example, let's say I want to select all users who are 21 and have a score between 400-500.

If they were actual columns, I would say:

```
SELECT * FROM tblUsers, tblData, WHERE UID=ID AND dataAge = 21 AND dataScore >= 400 AND dataScore <= 500
```

However, I can't do this because dataAge and dataScore aren't columns - they are rows in the dataTable like such:

```
    UID  dataType  dataValue
    35   1         21         //user #35's age (dataType 1)
    35   2         467        //user #35's score (dataType 2)
    49   1         21
    49   2         491
```

I cannot predict what dataTypes will be required in the future.
Users could arbitrarily add dataTypes about themselves, and not all users will have all possible data types at once.

I imagine also using another table, for text data, with the same format, UID, dataType, dataString.

Lets say I write

```
SELECT * FROM tblUsers, tlbData, WHERE UID=ID AND dataType=1 AND dataValue=21 AND dataType=2 AND dataValue >= 400 AND dataValue <= 500
```

because I want to compare both Age and Score, both dataType and dataValue are used ambiguously in the same call...

My question: What's the best table structure for my needs OR how can I properly query my current set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A User must fulfill all criteria in your query, so you have to join `tblData` multiple times, just like it were multiple tables:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   tblUsers u
JOIN   tblData d1 ON d1.uid = u.id AND d1.dataType=1 AND d1.dataValue=21
JOIN   tblData d2 ON d2.uid = u.id AND d2.dataType=2
                                   AND d2.dataValue BETWEEEN 400 AND 500
```

---

#### Answer to additional question in comments

For this to be performant, **indexes** are crucial. In particular case you will probably need the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX tbldata_uid_idx ON tblData(uid);
CREATE INDEX tbldata_datatype_datavalue_idx ON tblData(dataType, dataValue);
```

I assume that `id` is the primary key of `tblUsers` and is indexed automatically as such.

Read about [multi-column indexes in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html).

JOIN performance has been increased recently, but is still lacking behind other database systems like Oracle, SQL Server or PostgreSQL where JOINs are handled *very* performant. MySQL is not the best choice for lots of JOINs and subqueries.

For your particular case (multiple joins that can be combined) bitmap index scans will provide top performance - a feature that is not present in MySQL. It has an "index_merge" feature so substitute for that.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much... I never realized you could do multiple joins of the same table in a row!

Comment: Hmm, now I'm starting to wonder about performance and scalability.
Let's say the average user has 20 additional data points to check. There would be 20 rows in tlbData for every row in tlbUsers.

The tlbData would continue to grow linearly like this.

To query, that would require 20 JOINs in a row, and that seems... slow?

Lets say the DB grew to 1GB, would that be a 20GB pass? Or would it be smart enough to cache the query results... or do it all in one pass? Hmmm...

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood: the key element will be indexes. For lots of joins and subqueries with big tables mysql may be not the best choice, but it can certainly do the job. I added an additional answer to my answer above.

Comment: Ah, once again thank you for putting me on the right track! For now I will use MySQL multi-indexing, but I really appreciate that you went as far as listing the bitmap indexing and other available technologies in case I need to swap out MySQL... great stuff!